# PHP automatically removes the last zero after the point, Why?

Tags: php

PHP automatically removes the last zero after the decimal point. Forinstance

```
 $number=29.10;
 $echo 'Number='. $number;
```

This will print

```
 Number = 29.1
```

instead of

```
Number = 29.10
```

I actually need the zero after the decimal place but to no avail.

Why is this so? Any idea or link about this, is very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The last 0 after the point is irrelevant

Comment: Use `sprintf()` or `money_format()` or `number_format()` there are lots to choose from and they are all mentioned in the manual

Comment: 29.1=29.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @nogad Well that makes the point nicely

Comment: alternative to @RiggsFolly solution you could just use a string `$number="29.10";` and i assume the dollar in front of the echo was a typo

Comment: Yh will look into it, but have you realised that `$number=08` prints `0`, This happens happens even when you use the functions @RiggsFolly mentioned

Comment: 08 is an (invalid) octal http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php "Prior to PHP 7, if an invalid digit was given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the rest of the number was ignored. Since PHP 7, a parse error is emitted. "

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Ahaha, I didn't know the existence of `money_format()`! Money is everywhere. Oh, what a shame! ---->x